# Eliminating gaps between MS Word application windows and screen edges

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code opens a new document, saves it and arranges two MS Word application windows side by side. However, there are some gaps between the edges of the screen and the application windows. What do I need to correct in the code to eliminate the gaps?

```
Sub SplitScreen()

    ' Define variables for active document and new document
    Dim ActiveDoc As Document
    Dim NewDoc As Document
    Set ActiveDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Create a new document with the same name as the active document and "_EN" appended
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    Set NewDoc = ActiveDocument
    NewDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=Left(ActiveDoc.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDoc.FullName, ".")) & "EN.docx"
    
    ' Set window size and position for active document
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Top = 0
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Left = 0
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Width = Application.UsableWidth / 2
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Height = Application.UsableHeight
          
    
    ' Set window size and position for new document
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Top = 0
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Left = Application.UsableWidth / 2
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Width = Application.UsableWidth / 2
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Height = Application.UsableHeight
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the position and width.

```vb
Sub SplitScreen_Adjust()

    ' Define variables for active document and new document
    Dim ActiveDoc As Document
    Dim NewDoc As Document
    Set ActiveDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Create a new document with the same name as the active document and "_EN" appended
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    Set NewDoc = ActiveDocument
    NewDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=Left(ActiveDoc.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDoc.FullName, ".")) & "EN.docx"
    
    Dim adjust As Long
    adjust = 1
    
    ' Set window size and position for active document
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Top = 0
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Left = 0 - adjust
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Width = (Application.UsableWidth / 2) + adjust
    ActiveDoc.ActiveWindow.Height = Application.UsableHeight
          
    
    ' Set window size and position for new document
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Top = 0
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Left = (Application.UsableWidth / 2) + adjust
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Width = (Application.UsableWidth / 2) + adjust
    NewDoc.ActiveWindow.Height = Application.UsableHeight
    
End Sub
```